# Empty Dataset Returned while performing Join

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, dataframe

I am reading 2 data frames from csv files.
However, when I join the 2 dataFrames, I am getting an empty dataset as a result of a join between them.

Here are the 2 data frames.

[image: DataFrames]

```
val dfAverage = amount.join(client,"clientCode")
  .groupBy(client("clientName")).agg(avg(amount("opAmount"))
  .as("average"))
  .select("clientName","average")
```

This is the code snippet of Join.
I am getting an empty dataFrame as a result, but the schema is correct.

[image: Empty DataFrame]

As I am new to Scala and Spark, I need help for this simple problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please don't use images use text in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


val client = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("Abhishek", "C1"), 
  ("XUELAN", "C2"),
  ("Xahir", "C3")

)).toDF("ClientName", "ClientCode")

client.show()


+----------+----------+
|ClientName|ClientCode|
+----------+----------+
|  Abhishek|        C1|
|    XUELAN|        C2|
|     Xahir|        C3|
+----------+----------+



val amount = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("C1", "C11",3122l), 
  ("C1", "C12",4312l), 
  ("C2", "C21",21431l), 
  ("C2", "C31",87588l), 
  ("C3", "C32",98769l), 
  ("C3", "C33",86567l), 
  ("C3", "C34",23112l)


)).toDF("ClientCode", "OperationCode" ,"opAmount")

amount.show()

+----------+-------------+--------+
|ClientCode|OperationCode|opAmount|
+----------+-------------+--------+
|        C1|          C11|    3122|
|        C1|          C12|    4312|
|        C2|          C21|   21431|
|        C2|          C31|   87588|
|        C3|          C32|   98769|
|        C3|          C33|   86567|
|        C3|          C34|   23112|
+----------+-------------+--------+

val dfAverage = amount.join(client,"clientCode") .groupBy(client("clientName"))
 .agg(avg(amount("opAmount")).as("average"))
  .select("clientName","average")

dfAverage.show()


+----------+-----------------+
|clientName|          average|
+----------+-----------------+
|  Abhishek|           3717.0|
|     Xahir|69482.66666666667|
|    XUELAN|          54509.5|
+----------+-----------------+
```

or

```
  import sqlContext.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    client.createOrReplaceTempView("client")
    amount.createOrReplaceTempView("amount")


   val result = spark.sqlContext.sql("SELECT 
   client.ClientName,avg(amount.opAmount)as average FROM amount JOIN client on 
    amount.ClientCode=client.ClientCode GROUP BY client.ClientName")


+----------+-----------------+
|ClientName|          average|
+----------+-----------------+
|  Abhishek|           3717.0|
|     Xahir|69482.66666666667|
|    XUELAN|          54509.5|
+----------+-----------------+
```